# Failed to upgrade Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I'm trying to upgrade `Hive` and encountered problem.

Form - `Hadoop 1.1.2` and `Hive 0.9.0`
To   - `Hadoop 2.9.0` and `Hive 2.3.2`

Below is the error popped up while running `initschema`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 1.1.2
```

I have upgraded `Hadoop` to the newer version `2.9.0`. Why it's still connecting to the older version of `Hadoop 1.1.2`?

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like your java classpath is still pointing at old libraries

Comment: @cricket_007 It worked. The probem solved. As you mentioned the problem occured because java classpath was pointing to old libraries. Thankyou!!!

Comment: @cricket_007 . Could you update the answer so that others might also find it useful. Thankyou

Comment: You can provide the answer yourself because you have more context about what changes you made

Comment: @cricket_007 . Okay Thankyou